# Netbeans 11 "module not found" and "package is not visible" error badges

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a fully working modular Java 11 project which builds and runs with no problems.

I am using Gradle 5.4.1 for build. The project uses the standard Gradle Java Plugin conventional layout. I'm also using the application plugin. I have modified the build.gradle as per the building Java 9 modules tutorial [here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/)

When I open the project in Netbeans 11 and look at my modules module.info.java there are error badges saying "module not found" next to all the requires statements. Also in all the classes that import from these modules I get error badges "package *package-name* is not visible, package *package-name* is declared in the unnamed module, but module *package-name* does not read it."

There is no unnamed package in my project all my source files have a package statement. The packages I'm importing from are part of JavaFX 11 and controlsFX 11 so I wouldn't have thought they have unnamed packages either.

I can execute the run task from Netbeans and the project compiles and runs no problem.

If I open the project in IntelliJ IDEA there are no error messages, suggesting a Netbeans specific problem.

Comment: Everything you use in your project that does not have module definition will become part of the "unnamed module" by default.